# select query with child

Tags: sql, oracle

When i wrote select query for two table, i want to be recommened how to write query.

below, there are existed two table(pseudo ddl).

```
CREATE PARENT(
IDX int primary key,
NAME varchar2(40)
)

CREATE CHILD(
PARENT_IDX int,
NAME varchar2(40)
)
```

and this is state of table.

Parent:

```
IDX    / NAME
1      / PARENT1
2      / PARENT2
3      / PARENT3
```

Child:

```
PARENT_IDX /  NAME 
1          / CHILD1
1          / CHILD2
2          / CHILD3
3          / CHILD4
3          / CHILD5
3          / CHILD6
```

I want to print parent list with all children in jsp page like below:

```
IDX    / NAME       /CHILD
1      / PARENT1    /CHILD1,CHILD2
2      / PARENT2    /CHILD3
3      / PARENT3    /CHILD4,CHILD5,CHILD6
```

What is the best solution for this using SQL in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 11g or higher, you can do join together the parent and child tables and use `LISTAGG()` to get the CSV formatting you want:

```
SELECT p.IDX,
       p.NAME,
       LISTAGG(COALESCE(c.NAME, 'NA'), ',') "CHILD"
FROM PARENT p
LEFT JOIN CHILD c
    ON p.IDX = c.PARENT_IDX
GROUP BY p.IDX
```

Comment: oh, thank you. i think it is best solution. i realize LISTAGG now. thank you.